# Running Raspberry PI in Docker

Tags: docker

So, there are lots of Docker on PI questions out there but I'm looking todo it the other way, or run Raspberry PI in a Docker image running on x64 based platform. Are there any images built for this? Or, is my best bet to just setup a container to emulate Arm?

Comment: The container technology was not created to do emulation although it can. There are some solutions for running with qemu.

Comment: Yeah, my feeling was that it would likely be QEMU in a container to emulate ARM and then Running the PIE image inside. Hoping to exhaust all other possible options before going that route though.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no docker containers exist for Raspberry Pi OS. However, you can convert the [Raspberry Pi Desktop OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/) .iso file to a Docker container using [`docker import`](https://medium.com/@SofianeHamlaoui/convert-iso-images-to-docker-images-4e1b1b637d75).